# Почему не виден com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient?

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток.

Целый день безрезультатно бью в бубен, после обновления `sdk` проект не видит `LocationClient`. 
Среда разработки Intellij IDEA, добавляю как обычно:

```
Import Module -> google-play-services_lib
```

Добавляю библиотеку и модуль `google-play-services_lib` в мой модуль проекта.

Не видит `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient` при этом остальные классы вроде `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` и `import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest` видны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocationClient` удален из `services_lib b` и заменен на `FusedLocationProviderApi` и `GeofencingApi`